# image not visible through css :after property

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

image stored in my PC is not visible when I display it through css: after property, but when I display an image through external link then that image is visible

not able to figure out the problem 
if anyone could help it would be great

thanks

```
.user-down-arrow::after {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('file:///C:/Users/Vidur/Desktop/html%20assignment/images/angle-arrow-down.svg');
    top: 10px;
    right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You need to serve the image through a local HTTP server.

Comment: This is due to security restrictions of the browser. It cannot access assets using file:// protocol from css, except through the address bar. If you want to test that image, you have to serve it via http/https protocol as the user above has mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can provide just the local image name, assuming it is in the same folder...

```
background-image: url("img1.png")
```

Comment: background:url("images/logo.png");

Comment: Can u try other location than "C" drive .